# Variable IBOutlet name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to have a variable outlet name?.
For example you have 10 labels (perhaps seats on bus). each has an outlet, seat1 seat2 etc.
Is it possible to have a for loop
that concatenates @"seat" to the increment integer. So that I can access seat1, seat2 outlet without having to specify it individually.
This doesn’t work but makes it a bit clearer what I am trying to achieve.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [seatarray count]; i++)
{
    [@”seat”  stringByAppendingString[ i stringValue]] = @””;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting iOS4 you can use `IBOutletCollection` which allows to connect multiple instances to a single outlet which represents an array of objects, e.g. IBOutletCollection which can store UILabels only:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *seats;
```

Comment: Be aware, though, that even though IBOutletCollection takes an NSArray, the order of the contents is unspecified, and is not always the order in which they were hooked up in IB. It's unfortunate, as this would be a great place to use them.

Comment: Unordered, but you can always use UIView tags and sort the array to get specific elements.

Comment: I was able to work around this limitation by simply overriding the getter and returning a sorted array based on tags.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to simply create the array yourself at load time:

```
self.seatarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:seat1, seat2, ..., seatN, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with key-value coding, something like (untested code)
`for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) { [self setValue:@"foo" forKey:[@"seat" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", i]];  }`