# Connect items to a (specific index in) an array from Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

This one ought to be a softball for the Objective-C pros out there:

Is there a way to connect an interface builder object to an element of an NSArray in Objective-C?  The connecting would normally be done with `IBOutlet`, as in:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
    //...
}
```

Can I put the labels in an NSArray and still attach them to objects in interface builder?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268972/variable-iboutlet-name

Comment: @aBitObvious:  Thanks.  Several searches did not bring up this answer for some reason.  Hopefully my question in conjunction with the previous "semi-duplicate" will make it easier for future searchers to find this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use IBOutletCollection, which is essentially an array of IBOutlets.
Use this property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(/*whatever object you want an array of e.g. UILabel*/) NSArray *seats;
```

You will be able to connect multiple objects of one type to this in Interface builder.

Comment: Thanks.  You should also make a note that to distinguish the elements in the array you have to use the `tag` property, which is an integer property of all classes that inherit from UIView and can be set in Interface Builder.  The ordering is not guaranteed, apparently.