# How to bind a buttons title to a particular value in an array IOS?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have six on-screen buttons whose titles need to correspond to six elements in an `NSMutableArray`, when the value in the array changes, I also need the title to change with it. I am having trouble figuring out how to create that constantly updating line to the button, I'm still quiet new to *objective-c development* as well as *Xcode*.

I also need to make sure that when there is no value at that particular index of the array, the button cannot be clicked on

here is an example of one of the buttons

```
- (IBAction)card1Pressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.userHasEnteredFirstNumber) { 
        if (!self.userHasEnteredSecondNumber) {
            self.secondNumber = [sender currentTitle];
        }
    }
    else{
        self.firstNumber = [sender currentTitle];
    }

}
```

The end goal is to have the user press two buttons, then chose weather to *add*, *subtract*, *multiply*, or *divide* them. After they pick one of those four operations, the values that the buttons were assigned to in the array will be removed and replaced with whatever the new number is. So after they do this once there will only be 5 numbers left in the array, then 4, then 3..... and so on.

The numbers will be drawn and added to an `NSMutable` array titled *currentHand*

UPDATE: Using UIOutletCollection I linked the buttons to the method like this
the link to the picture is here "sorry about not being able to directly post it but new users must have a reputation of 10 before they can"
[link to photo of declaration and implementation with interface-builder of IBOutletCollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruW0Q.png)

was this correct?

the code for the header file regarding the IBOutletCollection is as follows "please note that this has been connected to the six buttons I want to use it with in interface builder, a picture of it is shown above"

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection (UIButton)NSArray *buttonArray;
```

the code in the implementation file regarding the IBOutletController is as follows

```
@ synthesize buttonArray = _buttonArray;
```

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't get exactly how this game (it's for a game, yes?) is supposed to work.

Comment: Did any of the answer help ? Please select a correct answer if yes.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Key-Value observing, check out this from the Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i

Answer (score 0):

Okay okay, so essentially you have a 'Button'-Array, whose 'Caption' is served by a NSMutableArray, which can easily be changed around, correct?

Now, this is only how I'd do it, there may be better solutions out there, but here goes:

You need a 'change' interface, which is called EACH time, something happens to your NSMutableArray. For example (since I don't know WHAT exactly is in that array of yours):

```
- (void) ChangeArray:(int)IDofElement (NSString *)newValue {
     [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:IDofElement withObject:newValue]; //Updates/Empties the indexed Element.
     if(newValue != nil) {   
         [buttons[IDOfElement] setText:newValue];
     }
     buttons[IDOfElement].enabled = (newValue != nil);      //Makes Button 'clickable'
}
```

Like this, each time the value inside that array of yours gets changed, the corresponding caption also gets updated. Of course you would need an array of the buttons for this to work, but I don't think that's the big problem.

Another possible solution: Save a reference to the button inside of the object that's stored in the array and whenever the value is changed, change the button's caption too.

Does this help? Mind you, this is not the 'perfect solution', but something I'd come up with.

Please also note, that this is just from the top of my head and probably faulty at some points. But it should be able to point you in the general direction.

Comment: thanks for this, I added some information above that might make what i'm doing clearer. I am  sorry for what is probably an obvious question, but how do I actually tie this method to a button in my application?

Comment: You're using the Interface Builder, yes? If so, you right click the button in question and select 'touch up' (or another listener). You then drag the line to the upper left item (sorry, I forgot the name, the delegate the XIB relates to) and then your method should pop up.

Comment: thanks, my next question is, how do you have an array of buttons? Sorry for the continuos stream of questions, my hope is that this thread might someday help someone as new as me.

Comment: @WilliamLouisRoach-Barrette There is not one question that does not deserve an answer, in my opinion. For this purpose, you will need to declare an IBOutletCollection as property in the interface and then fill it with the buttons in the Interface Builder. Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402801/connect-items-to-a-specific-index-in-an-array-from-interface-builder. Alternatively, create a regular array (UIButton *buttons[6]) in interface and fill it manually, using the properties of the buttons.

Comment: thanks, I think im on the right track. I posted a link to a screenshot of how I declared and implemented the IBOutletCollection, i synthesized it like I would anything else in the implementation file. How do I now incorporate the method written above with the IBOutletCollection?

Comment: You've got the method itself set up? And linked it to the buttons?

Comment: well, no. Ive literally just inputed the code I added above, I also connected the buttons to the @property in the header file using interface-builder, I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: Well, connect the buttons to the IBAction in question. Unfortunately SO is nagging me to NOT do discussion in the comments (and it's right about that). I'm sure there are some tutorials, which can guide you on the next step. And if you get stuck again, open a new question. Maybe we'll meet again there, maybe someone more capable will answer :)